# Unable to create notification using glide

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-glide, firebase-notifications

I am receiving data using fcm and i want to create a notification which contains an image.When i get this data i get the url of the image that i try loading using glide but glide refuses to fire from the service [ **FirebaseMessagingService** ]

```
    public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

private final String TAG = getClass().getName();

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

    try {

        if (remoteMessage.getData().containsKey("notification")) {

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Notif notif = gson.fromJson(remoteMessage.getData().get("notification"), Notif.class);

            politicoDataRepository.getPolitico(notif.getPolitico_id())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(politico -> {

                            createNotifiation(notif, getApplicationContext());

                    }, throwable -> Log.e("Error", throwable.getMessage() + " " + TAG));

        } else {
            Log.i("datFirebase", remoteMessage.getFrom() + "  " + remoteMessage.getData().get("id"));
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        realm.close();
    }


}

private void createNotifiation(Notif notif, Context context) {

    final RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_item);

    remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.notif_image, R.mipmap.ic_launcher);


    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle(notif.getTitle())
                    .setContentText(notif.getMessage())
                    .setContent(remoteViews)
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MIN);

    final Notification notification = mBuilder.build();

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
        mBuilder.setCustomBigContentView(remoteViews);
    }


    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(141, notification);


    NotificationTarget notificationTarget = new NotificationTarget(this, remoteViews, R.id.notif_image, notification, 141);

    Glide.with(this)
            .load(notif.getImage())
            .asBitmap()
            .into(notificationTarget);

}
```

}

Comment: Please add log,

Code is written correctly.

Comment: The only output i get is notif.getId() and notif.getimage(),i dont get an output from the glide part.

Comment: Please add code from where you are calling createNotifiation method.

Comment: @KeyurThumar added more code

Comment: Please check remoteMessage whether you are getting image url

Comment: @KeyurThumar the current code works right now but it only displays the image as an icon,i want an expandable notification so when the user swipes down on the notification with both fingers the big style image should be shown.

Answer (score 1):

try with **NotificationTarget**. Here is the link [Glide — Loading Images into Notifications and AppWidgets](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-loading-images-into-notifications-and-appwidgets)

Or you can try like this

> remoteViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.noti_article_1_imageview, getBitmapFromURL
>           (selectedList[0].getImageUrl()));
>
> remoteViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.noti_article_2_imageview, getBitmapFromURL
>           (selectedList[1](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-loading-images-into-notifications-and-appwidgets).getImageUrl()));

```
public Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String strURL) {
    try {
      URL url = new URL(strURL);
      HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
      connection.setDoInput(true);
      connection.connect();
      InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
      Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
      return myBitmap;
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Comment: I have used the link you provided and it worked but the notification is just a simple notification and i would like to display and expanded notification or a big style notification.How can i do that?

Comment: try to expand noti in noti panel. Sometimes it only shows small style if there no space. ( if ur code is correct)

Answer (score 0):

```
   @Override
      public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
    // this will update the UI with message

    Log.d("Keyur", " received broadcast");
    new CreateNotification(context).execute();
}

/**
 * Notification AsyncTask to create and return the
 * requested notification.
 */
public class CreateNotification extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;

    private Context con;

    public CreateNotification(Context context) {
        con = context;
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context
                .NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    }

    /**
     * Creates the notification object.
     *
     * @see #setBigPictureStyleNotification
     */
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Notification noti = new Notification();

        noti = setBigPictureStyleNotification();

        noti.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
        noti.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        noti.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

        noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE;


        mNotificationManager.notify(0, noti);

        return null;

    }

    /**
     * Big Picture Style Notification
     *
     * @return Notification
     * @see CreateNotification
     */
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    private Notification setBigPictureStyleNotification() {
        Bitmap remote_picture = null;

        // Create the style object with BigPictureStyle subclass.
        NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle notiStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle();
        notiStyle.setBigContentTitle("YourQuote");
        notiStyle.setSummaryText("#BeMotivated #BeInspried");
        //notiStyle.setSummaryText("Nice big picture.Nice big picture.Nice big picture.Nice big " +
        //"picture.Nice big picture.Nice big picture.Nice big picture.Nice big picture" +
        // ".Nice big picture.");


        try {
            /*remote_picture = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(UrlUtils
                    .getUrlUtils().getUrl())
                    .getContent());*/
            remote_picture = new CreateAndSaveBitmap().drawMultilineTextToBitmap(con,
                    BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(UrlUtils
                            .getUrlUtils().getUrl())
                            .getContent()),
                    UrlUtils
                            .getUrlUtils
                                    ().getQuota());
            Log.d("Keyur", "image is downloaded");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Add the big picture to the style.
        notiStyle.bigPicture(remote_picture);

        // Creates an explicit intent for an ResultActivity to receive.
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(con, MainActivity.class);

        // This ensures that the back button follows the recommended convention for the back key.
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(con);

        // Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself).
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(ResultActivity.class);

        // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack.
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        return new NotificationCompat.Builder(con)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                .setAutoCancel(true)

                .setLargeIcon(remote_picture)

                .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                //.addAction(R.drawable.icon, "SHARE", resultPendingIntent)
                .setSubText("#BeMotivated #BeInspried")
                .setContentTitle("YourQuote")
                .setStyle(notiStyle).build();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Jude Fernandes here is a sample code for big picture notification.

Comment: This answer may be missing some explanation. Code-only answers are not very useful.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev That is the reason why I comment in the code.